# How do I scroll up in my terminal window?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I wanted to see a list of the applications installed on my "Trusty Tahr"
I ran this command in the terminal

```
 dpkg --list
```

I got a list that displayed fine except that it cuts off about halfway the list, I can't see any applications prior to application names starting with the letter "P". How can I scroll past that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the results in to `less` and then then use your arrow keys to scroll the list.

```
dpkg --list | less
```

If you want it in the GUI way, you can increase the number of lines to scroll-back. To do this, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Profile. Select the desired profile and then Edit. Go to the Scrolling tab and change the value of "Limit scrollback to..." to the desired number of lines.

[image]